# Get list of table columns used in a stored procedures, view, functions

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, database-administration

I have a table which has 50 columns and I want to find out, what are the column names are actually used in stored proc, views, functions etc. Is there any query that I can used which will table name, used column name and the stored proc name where it is used.

I used following query which returns only the stored proc/view where this table is used. But I need the only used column name from this table, table name and stored proc name.

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID),
definition, *
FROM sys.sql_modules
WHERE definition LIKE '%' + 'tablename ' + '%'
```

Example:

Table Name:

```
Employee
```

Columns:

```
First Name
Last Name
Age
Email
```

If First name, Last name only is used in whole database, then it should only return those two columns.

Comment: Seems like a similar query to what this questioner is using would probably do the trick. https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/265974/3690

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft has a sp that shows the object dependency called: **sp_depends**

```
EXEC sp_depends 'Employee'
```

Will give you all the objects that depends on Employee

see link for more detail : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-depends-transact-sql

Now to get the columns it has a function **sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities()** to list all columns.

```
SELECT
        referenced_id,
        referenced_entity_name AS table_name,
        referenced_minor_name  AS referenced_column_name,
        is_all_columns_found
    FROM
        sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities ('sp_MyProcOrView', 'OBJECT');
```

see link for more detail https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-sql-referenced-entities-transact-sql

You should be able to find the columns used with these two features.